How do I find $\max_{0\le x\le1}\left|\left(x-\frac{i}n\right)\left(x-\frac{n-i}n\right)\right|$, given $i\in\{0,1, \dots, n\}$?

Show that $$\max\limits_{0 \ < \ x \ < \ 1} \left|\left(x-\frac{i}{n}\right)\left(x - \frac{n-i}{n}\right)\right|\leq \frac{1}{4}, \quad i= 0,1, \cdots, n.$$

I'm trying to find the maximum of this function in its given interval. Since it's a quadratic equation, I found the vertex, which is $x = \tfrac{1}{2}$, but when I plugged it back into the base equation, I got $\left|\dfrac{1}{4} - \left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)^2\right|$.
Now, I originally thought that since $\left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)^2$ is always positive, there is no way for $\tfrac{1}{4}$ to get bigger, but the absolute value signs quashed that idea. Can someone help me figure out where I went wrong here?

@Moo It was irrelevant.

I don't think so in this case, because "what was posted" was a badly formatted image, and the thoughts of the OP are not referring to that part of the image.

e^x is meant for a different section of the question.

Write the function as $|(x-\frac12)^2 - (\frac12 - \frac{i}{n})^2|$. Now let $y=\frac{i}{n}$ so that $0\le y\le 1$ and the function becomes $|(x-\frac12)^2 - (y-\frac12)^2|$. Defining $x'=x-\frac12$ and $y'=y-\frac12$, we have $-\frac12 \le x',y'\le \frac12 \implies 0\le x'^2,y'^2 \le \frac14$ and the function is $|x'^2 - y'^2|$. It is now clear why this quantity is at most $\frac14$.

More generally,
$$\forall x,y\in[0,1]\quad|(x-y)(x+y-1)|=|(x^2-x)-(y^2-y)|
\le\frac14$$
since $x^2-x,y^2-y\in[-1/4,0]$.
Alternatively, fixing your attempt: given $y\in[0,1]$, consider the quadratic function $$f(x):=x^2-x-y^2+y,$$ Then, $\min(f)=f(1/2)=c-1/4$ where $c:=f(0)=f(1)=-y^2+y\in[0,1/4]$. Therefore,
$$\max_{0\le x\le1}|f(x)|=\max(c,1/4-c)\le1/4.$$
